# ASP .Net, Redirect to an external page while POSTING data

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, http-post

Hi I have a requirement to deal with an external API in MY ASP.Net Application.

There in a button click in my application, I have to redirect the user to an external URL at the same time POSTING some user credentials(username, password) to allow access to there (The external 3rd party page).

If I try to access to that external page without posting credentials(Just a redirect) I will not be able to view the required page and istead an error message saying invalid credentials(From the 3rd party page).

Suppose following are the information

```
1. URL need to access : https://externalurl.com/external-page.asp
2. username           : myusername
3. password           : mypassword
```

- If I do a simple HTML form submission it works brilliantly as follows.

[image]

No Idea of how to do this in C# code in ASP .Net.

I can post the data using `WebRequest` APIs but no way to redirect in the same session. If someone can guide on doing this would be great. Thanks in advance...!!!

**Edits...**

1. In my case I can't use javascript or any client side scripting to do this.
2. Basically I don't have to read any response for my POST data. I need to redirect to that page(External location while posting information)

Comment: Try to use this class WebClient

Comment: Why is the form-posting solution insufficient?  Without client side scripting I see that as the only way unless you utilize your server as a proxy between the client and the external server.  In other words, you wouldn't be redirecting the client, rather acting as a middle man communicating to/from both parties (external server and client).

Comment: Hi mikey, Yes I am willing to use form submission if this is not possible to do with any ASP.Net APIs. But the username and password values have to be dynamically set according to different users. Bit confussing of how to do this in here. If you can explain bit in detail, it's wonderful. Thanks....

Comment: @JibW - "the username and password values have to be dynamically set according to different users" <-- set by you I assume (because those inputs are hidden?).  If so, you can do <input runat="server" type="hidden" id="hUsername"...etc.  Then in your code-behind / page load you can simply to hUsername.Value = <username> or hUsername.Text = <username> (I don't recall the exact property).  Or I am pretty sure you could even do something like <input ...etc... value="<%= getUsername()%>"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an `HttpWebRequest`, but you need to cache your credentials so that they get passed with each request, not just the first; like this:

```
// Set queryUrl to your URL, either hard-coded or passed in
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(queryUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

// Set your credentials
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(username, pwd, domain); 

// Setup cache to store your credentials for future requests
var cache = new CredentialCache {{queryUrl, "Ntlm", cred}};
req.Credentials = cache;

HttpWebResponse response = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this to your button

`<asp:Button ID="Button1" PostBackUrl="https://externalurl.com/external-page.asp" runat="server" Text="Submit" /`>

Hope this is clear

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX

Comment: I tried this, But how to post data in this way? In my case "username : myusername" AND "password : mypassword"

Comment: have just 2 textbox and the button and be sure that the client id of text box matches with 'username' and password. you can try setting the clientid mode to static. or use jquery as explaned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350674/passing-variables-with-post-to-another-page-with-jquery

Comment: I just did this. Just created two textboxes and named the ID fields exactly like that and added PostBackUrl property. It tries to access the location but data doesn't post... Therefore I see the error message when I see with a normal redirect....

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the form method and action exactly like you have it now. Or use a postbackURL on the button.

The problem is going to be setting the name on the elements to be able to submit them.  You have to use javascript to set the hidden fields.  Because .net changes the "name" property of the rendered elements on server-side controls.

So, on the client side click event of the button, you can set the values of the hidden fields (just like the ones in your question) to whatever values you need.  And, when the form submits, they will be posted with the proper names.